# ContentHuggingPriority and CompressionResistance not honored by StackView with custom control as subview

Tags: ios, uikit, constraints, interface-builder, uistackview

I've created a horizontal `UIStackView` with two subviews:

1. A `UILabel`.
2. A custom `UIControl`.

I would like the Label to expand within the view and for the Control to hug its content.

`Content Hugging Priority` is set to (in Interface Builder):

- Label: 240, Control: 255

`Content Compression Resistance Priority` is set to (in Interface Builder):

- Label: 756, Control: 732

As you can see in the screenshot below, the label is being hugged by its bounds and the control is expanding to fill the remaining space, which is the opposite of what I've specified in the size inspector.

What am I missing here?

[image: Screenshot of StackView]

Other Notes:

- I don't have any other constraints set for Label or Control.
- The StackView's spacing is set to 0 and it has leading and trailing constraints set to its superview.
- If I remove the custom control and just add another label to the StackView, the hugging and resistance properties work as expected.

Comment: Does your custom control override the `intrinsicContentSize` property?

Comment: What **content** does your custom control have to ***hug***?

Comment: @HangarRash it does not.

Comment: @DonMag it contains a StackView with a label and an ImageView as its subviews.

Comment: @SemperFly - OK... you need to configure your custom control to handle content hugging / compression-resistance priorities. Is your custom control code-only? Or are you creating it with a xib? Show us the code for your custom control class.

Comment: @DonMag I was able to solve and posted my solution below. I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve it by doing the following.

1. The custom control contained a horizontal stack view with two subviews. I removed the stack view, replaced it with a view as the new parents of the subviews, and added constraints to achieve the look I was going for.
2. Programmatically, within the initialization function of the parent view, I called `customControl.sizeToFit()` followed by `setNeedsLayout()` after calling `setupNibView()`.

Comment: If that is sufficient for you, great. But... You **can** use Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance Priorities if you've configured your custom control properly.

Comment: For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhfvp.png ... note that this is in Storyboard/IB, with the custom control set as `@IBDesignable`

Comment: @DonMag It was sufficient for me, thanks!!!

Comment: As a general rule here -- if you post a question, then decide to do something else, you should either close or delete the question.

Comment: I’m sure the person who stumbles upon this in X years and realizes they just need to call sizeToFit if their custom control isn’t behaving will be thankful I left it up. I do appreciate your dedication to bureaucracy.